# Open Serial connection from Java running on PC to android device

Tags: java, android, serial-port, uart, android-hardware

I've been looking around and I'm not sure if this is possible through just software. I have a jar that I've built that scans for a serial device and connects and sends data. I can do this easily to an arduino. But I am also needing to access an android device through serial for a project I'm working on. I'm not sure how to get a PC to detect this device as serial though

Comment: Android doesn't expose a serial interface normally. There's a USB port. You may be able to run some emulation application on the phone? Maybe there's an App for that.

Comment: Well I see some serial APIs for android but they all seem to be for host android to another peripheral device. If I can do it through some other API that I havent come across. In the android sdk all I see is android.hardware.usb